# Laravel relationships many to many with recursive users table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables users and payments

The users table is as follows:

```
id
fisrtname
lastname
```

The payments table is as follows:

```
id
users_id
receiver_id
```

NB: users table is also receivers table.

I would like to have the list of users who have made a payment and not received any payment

Comment: Hi, Would be better if you enhance your payment details table for a comprehensive check. eg have a flag to check if payment is successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try my solution:

```php
class User extends Authenticatable {
    ...
    public function payments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Payment::class, 'users_id');
    }
}
```

```php
$users = \App\User::query()->getModel();
$users = $users->whereHas('payments', function ($query) {
    /** @var Builder $query */
    $query->havingRaw('COUNT(*) = 1');
})->whereNotExists(function ($query) {
    /** @var Builder $query */
    $query->select(['receiver_id'])
      ->from('payments')
      ->whereRaw('users.id = payments.receiver_id');
})->get();
```

Comment: i got this error: ```Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'monprofi.payments.id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select * from `users` where exists (select * from `payments` where `users`.`id` = `payments`.`user_id` having COUNT(*) = 1) and not exists (select `receiver_id` from `payments` where users.id = payments.receiver_id))```

Comment: solve the problem by set strict to false on cofing/database.php file. Thank you !!!